# Local SQL Express for ASP.NET/Sharepoint Development?

Tags: asp.net, development-environment, sql-server-express

In your development environment, do you install a local SQL express or a dedicated SQL server? What are the pro/con's of these two options?

From my own experience so far:

- Local installation slows down the own development workstation due to resource consumption
- Local installation is easier to debug/manage
- Dedicated installation eases central administration (backup, etc)

What are your personal experiences and suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on how busy you expect the app to be & any cost restrictions (number of boxes, rack space etc.). If it's a low traffic inter / intranet server I'd be inclined put them on the same box. If the SQL was a small part of a busy web server, separate them. If you encapsualte them well enough then the deployment differences are a matter of configuration, rather than re-coding. ie. Code for both eventualities.

SQL Express can only use 1GB of RAM & a 4GB database - it will get only-so busy.

Answer (score 1):

Local is useful when working on a laptop/from home where don't have access to a network.

Also useful when want to work on isolation from other developers and not worry about someone elses work on the same database / other activities on the server slowing you down.

I work on the server but use a local instance for the above cases